# iCloud backup miscalculations

Tags: ipad, icloud, backup

I'm using an iPad mini 2 with the latest version of iOS (9.3.2). For several months I have not been able to back up to iCloud because I supposedly don't have enough space available. This seems to be due to the space *calculation*, not the actual space that should be taken up. I currently have 4.2 GB available in iCloud. I have turned off the backing up of the majority of my apps because there are only a few I care about. However, iCloud still calculates that the next backup size will be 6.3 GB even though, if I add up the data listed, it should be about 753.5 MB. The calculation problems have existed for months, and I'm not sure what to do. I guess I *could* spend $0.99 a month to get 50 gigs and make it shut up, and iTunes backup works, but I'd rather use this like I have been for years.

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes. Wow. That's quite a difference.

Comment: There’s been a big problem with iCloud backups since iOS 9. You can find reports about this issue on a number of forums. Apple issued fixes for this throughout the various updates, but it’s still ongoing. I disabled iCloud backups altogether because my backups had ballooned to 8+ GB for each of my devices.